# SQL Profiler Shows Update (EventClass) with No Errors, But Data in Table is Not Changed

Tags: sql-server, profiler, query-timeout

I am trying to debug a web app that uses a database and I need a little help.  The problem is that part of the code throws a timeout error.  I started using `SQL Server Profiler` to check the communication between the app and the database.  (I am not really a database expert and this is a new tool for me).

The app is supposed to call an `UPDATE` on a specific record.  Shortly after, it calls a `SELECT` on the same record (because it refreshes the screen).  I can see both the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` event classes in the Profiler trace.  (There are a few other event classes between them).  The `SELECT` is showing with a duration of 30499 and an Error of `2 - Abort`.  I am guessing this is the source of my timeout error.

This is where it gets interesting.  By selecting the `EventClass` in the Profiler trace, I can see the SQL `SELECT` statement that is being called.  I copied and pasted this into a new query in Management Studio and tried it out.  The `SELECT` statement worked fine and returned the record before my finger left the f5 key.  However, the data in the record was the old data.  It seems that the previous `UPDATE` call did not change the record.

Looking at the Profiler trace again, the `UPDATE` event class shows an Error of `0 - OK`.  When I select the `UPDATE` event class and copy the SQL code into Management Studio it runs fine and does update the record.  Is anyone able to help me work out what is going on please.

1. If the `UPDATE` statement is shown in Profiler with no error, then does this mean that it should have updated the database?
2. What could be causing the `SELECT` statement to abort (considering that it runs fine when I try it in SQL Server Management Studio)?
3. Could problems with the `UPDATE` be causing the record to lock up which stop the `SELECT` from running?

Any advice to help me debug and fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If the `UPDATE` statement is shown in Profiler with no error, then does this mean that it should have updated the database?*

Yes, but whether the change is **visible** to other database connections depends on whether the change is committed or not, and on the current [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) in use by the other connection. To be clear, the [SQL:BatchCompleted Profiler Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) is triggered when a T-SQL batch completes, it does not mean that any containing transaction has also committed.

> *What could be causing the `SELECT` statement to abort (considering that it runs fine when I try it in SQL Server Management Studio)?*

In your case, the update was performed inside a transaction which was not committed. The `SELECT` statement was issued on a separate database connection under an isolation level that does not permit reading uncommitted data. From the description given, the `SELECT` was blocked by the exclusive lock held by the uncommitted change.

The fact that you were able to issue the `SELECT` and have it return the pre-update version of the row means your Management Studio session was using a [row-versioning isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx), almost certainly `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`.

The `SELECT` issued from the application must be running under a different isolation level, one that does not use row-versioning, and blocks when it encounters an exclusive lock, perhaps `SERIALIZABLE`. You should check the application code to determine this.

> *If you know of a way to show uncommitted update calls in Profiler (rather than an error-free update followed by an abort on a select) then can you add this as an answer please? This would help a lot when I am debugging this code.*

There are lots of options here. You might find also tracing the [SQLTransaction Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186239.aspx) sufficient for your needs. Alternatively, there are many system views and commands to help you see uncommitted transactions. You may find a query like the following useful to show details for open user transactions:

```
SELECT
    DES.session_id,
    DES.[host_name],
    DES.[program_name],
    DES.login_name,
    DES.last_request_start_time,
    DES.reads,
    DES.writes,
    transaction_isolation_level =
        CASE DES.transaction_isolation_level
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Read Uncomitted'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Read Committed'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable Read'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot'
        END,
    DES.open_transaction_count,
    DTDT.database_transaction_begin_time,
    transaction_state =
        CASE DTDT.database_transaction_state
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Not initialized'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Initialized'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Open and has generated log records'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Prepared'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'Committed'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'Aborted'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'Being committed'
        END
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS DES
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions AS DTST
    ON DTST.session_id = DES.session_id
JOIN sys.dm_tran_database_transactions AS DTDT
    ON DTDT.database_id = DES.database_id
WHERE 
    DES.is_user_process = 1
    AND DTST.is_user_transaction = 1
    AND DTDT.database_transaction_type = 1
    AND DES.open_transaction_count > 0;
```

The system views used in that code are all documented in Books Online:

[sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx)
[sys.dm_tran_session_transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188739.aspx)
[sys.dm_tran_database_transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957.aspx)

You may also find [`DBCC OPENTRAN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx) useful as a way to quickly see the longest open transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to fix this problem.  Turns out that the data access handler in the application code should have called commit after the `UPDATE` call, but this was missing.

Based on my limited understanding, the access handler (based on Interop.COMSVCSLib) is using a buffer(?) built in to SQL Server.  For some reason, I expected this buffer to be external to the database.

Thus `SQL Server Profiler` was capturing the `UPDATE` call even though the update was not being committed.  When the `SELECT` was called, presumably SQL Server was still waiting for the update to be committed and so caused the timeout.  When the `UPDATE` failed to be committed then SQL Server caused the data to be thrown away and the old data was preserved.

(If someone wants to write a more detailed answer that can help me understand this process better then I will mark it as the answer, since I don't really like answering my own questions).

Comment: @PaulWhite Thanks for your comment, I had thought that update calls from the data access layer would only be seen in Profiler after the commit, but I guess I was wrong.  If you know of a way to show uncommitted update calls in Profiler (rather than an error-free update followed by an abort on a select) then can you add this as an answer please?  This would help a lot when I am debugging this code.